# Unable to cast the type 'x' to type 'y'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, casting

I have classes that drive from Base class "**BaseTask**"

- Task1
- Task2
- Task3

  ```
    return DbContext.Projects.Include(t => t.Tasks).Select(p => new ProjectDto
      {
          Id = p.Id,
          Name = p.Name,
          Tasks = p.Tasks.Select(t => new TaskDto()
          {
              Id = t.Id,
              Name = t.Name,
              ProjectId = t.ProjectId,
              Selector = !(t is Task1) ? t.Selector : null,
              Task2Property = (t is Task2) ? ((Task2)t).Task2Property : null,
              SelectorPosition = (t is Task3) ? ((Task3)t).SelectorPosition : null,
              KeyId = t.KeyId
          }).ToList()
      }
      );
  ```

This part of the code returns the following error:

> Unable to cast the type 'Task' to type 'Task1'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.

how can I fix this issue?

Comment: Perform DTO conversion after Materialiaing the `IQueryable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK this is not possible with EF in that way, as EF can't translate that to SQL. But maybe a small structural change would help:

```
return DbContext.Projects.Include(t => t.Tasks).Select(p => new ProjectDto
    {
        Id = p.Id,
        Name = p.Name,
        Tasks = p.Tasks.Select(t => new TaskDto()
        {
            Id = t.Id,
            Name = t.Name,
            ProjectId = t.ProjectId,
            Task = t,
            KeyId = t.KeyId
        }).ToList()
    });
```

and in the `TaskDto`:

```
public X Selector => (Task as Task1)?.Selector;
public X Task2Property => (Task as Task2)?.Task2Property;
public X SelectorPosition => (Task as Task3)?.SelectorPosition;
```

Where `X` is the appropriate type for each property (and `=>` the short form for `{ get { return x; } }` if you are still using an older version of C#).

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an older question, but as I was solving the same problem, I finally found out an interesting solution. Maybe it will help someone else. If you use a direct cast, it does not work, but if you use `as` syntax instead, EF is magically able to translate it. This should work, or at least it does in my case.

```
Selector = (t as Task1).Selector,
Task2Property = (t as Task2).Task2Property,
SelectorPosition = (t as Task3).SelectorPosition,
```

If the type is not correct, the value is null, so it has the same result you wanted to achieve.

Comment: This was a lifesaver for me, thank you for posting this!